# Adding string to string as an argument?

Tags: arduino

I have a function which gets 2 parameters which i would like to insert as a part of a new string creating :

```
boolean connectToWifi(String ssid, String pass )
{
  String connection="wifi.sta.config("myssid","my password") ;
```

I would like to have `connection` , to be with the 2 arguments that this function gets ( `missed->said` , `my password->pass` )

How would i create such a string ?

Comment: You need to escape the " like this \"

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
connection="wifi.sta.config(\""+ssid+"\",\""+pass+"\")" ;
```

Comment: thank you , but this is not what i wants, i would like to INSERT in this string, the parameters that i get in the function . sure i have to add the "\" , my mistake, but i need a way to insert the function parameters inside that string ....

Comment: See updated code. If it does no do what you want then clarify further.

Comment: `connection="wifi.sta.config("+ssid+","+pass+")";` The ssid and pass parameters are already strings, you only need a + to add them in with other strings.